# asking for suggestions on modelling the data structure of my PDP emulator

Tags: rust

(Please dont close as a being a subjective question - I am asking for advice from fellow travelers on the 'discovering rust idioms' track)

I am porting my PDP11 emulator from c++ to rust. I am trying to get the right data structures.

Logically a PDP11 system consists of a CPU, a bus (that owns all the IO devices) and some ram. Each component needs to talk to each other. So I started with this

```
pub struct System {
    ram: Memory,
    cpu: Cpu,
    bus: Bus,
}
```

And lets look at one function

```
impl Cpu{
    pub fn step(&self) -> (){
        let inst = ram.get_word(self.pc);
       // decode inst
       // execute it
    }
}
```

single step. The core of the emulator. It needs access to the ram (and the bus but not shown here). OF course this is incomplete and doesnt have a way to get at the ram

My first effort was then to some how wire up these 'child' structs to have pointers back to this system object. No can do, they need to be mut in both directions, chaos ensues.

Then I thought that since there is only one of each thing I just flatten the whole thing into one object, all the methods and data exist on the system object. But thats just not clean, these are logically distinct subsystems that I really want to model as separate entities .

Then I had a revelation. What would rust want me to do? Pass into the function calls the data it needs. Like this

```
impl System{  
  pub fn step(&mut self){
        self.cpu.step(&mut self)
    }
}
```

and

```
impl Cpu{
    pub fn step(&self, &mut sys:System) -> (){
        let inst = sys.ram.get_word(self.pc);
       // decode inst
       // execute it
    }
}
```

(There is a UI calling these System methods higher up the stack via FFI). Now I know that this doesn't work and have read why it does work.

I have been stuck for a week now trying to work out whats the best way to arrange these structures. Any advice please?

Comment: "Please dont close as a being a subjective question - I am asking for advice from fellow travelers on the 'discovering rust idioms' track" how this make your question not opinion / off topic ? that not because you ask it that it make your question ok - - I don't understand your behaviour here this question is suitable for Rust forum or a rust chat. Not stackoverflow

Comment: I agree with Stargateur that this question is too opinion based for SO. But in case it helps, I solved a very similar problem in this [project](https://github.com/rodrigorc/raze) of mine.

Comment: well the question gets two upvotes so there are counter opinions:-)

Comment: @rodrigo - wow that is such a subtle difference from what I tried. (Using your names) I had Game as one struct with bus mem z80. You have Game with z80 and contained struct ULA with bus and mem. The huge difference is that you can pass ula to z80 function, you cannot pass Game to z80 function. YOu have saved me from Rc, Refcell, ... hell. Make it an answer

Answer (score 1):

> My first effort was then to some how wire up these 'child' structs to have pointers back to this system object

That would be a bad idea in C++ too (or any language, really). Cycles are bad!

> Pass into the function calls the data it needs.

Yes, that is a solution that can be seen in many projects out there, but take into account that you are *also* creating a cycle. In this case, the cycle is temporary rather than permanent, but it is still a cycle.

Instead, what you can to do is pass only the subsystems that the first subsystem needs. This removes the cycle. Or even just the pieces of a subsystem you may need.

> Then I thought that since there is only one of each thing I just flatten the whole thing into one object, all the methods and data exist on the system object. But thats just not clean, these are logically distinct subsystems that I really want to model as separate entities .

Perhaps, but take into account that in many cases real-life entities are not the best partitioning points when modeling a system.

When you have subsystems that depend on many of the other subsystems or even the entire system, perhaps creating cycles, then it *might* be a symptom that the partition you chose is not the best.

If you want to keep the subsystems separated as they are and avoiding cycles turns out to be impossible, you can resort to solutions like `RefCell` or copy semantics.